# Is there an equivalent to MFCs OnUpdate in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I have an existing application that uses MFC for the UI, and I'm trying to migrate to Qt. For the most part the migration is straight forward, but I'm not sure how to manage the enabled state of actions (menu and toolbar items).

In MFC you implement a callback with enable/disable logic, and this is called when the item is displayed. In Qt, you only have access to the setEnabled() method.

Is there a built-in or standardized way of connecting an update callback to an action? or do I need to create my solution using timers and registering actions with it? In a large application such as the one I'm working with, the 'should enable' logic can jump all over the place - i.e. certain files on disk must exist, the main display must have a selection, the application's ProcessManager::isProcessing() must be false, etc. It doesn't seem practical to rely on setEnabled() being called on specific actions when there are so many conditions behind the enable/disable logic.

Answer (score 1):

The most "standard" Qt way would be the use of signals/slots.

In my MDI apps, which are based on the Qt MainWindow/MDI examples, I just connect a single "updateMenus()" function to the signal emitted whenever an MDI subwindow is shown or hidden.

Now that may not be enough granularity for your application. So what you could do is - still have a single "updateMenus()" method - but connect it to each menu's "aboutToShow()/aboutToHide()" signals.

That way you keep the logic from sprawling all over the place, and only update menus right when they are needed (like in MFC's OnCmdUI()).

Here's my mainwindow constructor:

```
mp_mdiArea = new QMdiArea();
setCentralWidget(mp_mdiArea);
connect(mp_mdiArea, SIGNAL(subWindowActivated(QMdiSubWindow*)), this, SLOT(updateMenus()));
```

And here's my updateMenus():

```
void MainWindow::updateMenus()
{
    bool hasMdiChild = (activeMdiChild() != nullptr);
    mp_actionSave->setEnabled(hasMdiChild);
    mp_actionSaveAs->setEnabled(hasMdiChild);
    mp_actionClose->setEnabled(hasMdiChild);
}
```

See Qt 4.8 doc for menu->aboutToShow()/Hide() [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#aboutToShow)

Comment: This solution could probably be made to work for menus, but I'd like to be able to implement it for actions in general. When you add an action to a menu and a toolbar, and disable the action, both the menu and toolbar respect the disabled state. With your approach in mind, and considering I do not have an aboutToShow() for actions in toolbars, it seems I'd have to have a sub-second timer constantly calling registered callbacks and passing the result to setEnabled() on the actions. This would work, but it'd be gross.

Comment: Yes, I agree you don't want to go the timer route. I'm sorry I was thinking in terms of menus-only. I guess if it was me, I would be OK with calling setEnabled() on the actions when the related item states changed. If I felt like the logic was peppered all over the place, I might route them through an "updateStates()" method in the main class - mainwindow, etc - but I can't see how the originating event could be handled anywhere but at the source. At least you could always find all of them by searching for the call to "updatStates()".